# lookup same collection multiple times, from embedded docuemnt in mongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have an embedded document of posts and comments. Where comments is an embedded document with user details `commentedby`. There is a good chance that user name changes often. So the value of user needs to be lookedup everytime a comment is accessed.

Is there a efficient way to do this using mongo query. **I don't prefer using unwind** Since I'll lose other post params on grouping again

```
{
    "PostId":"Post001",
    "Comments":[
         {"_id": "001",
          "CommentedBy":{
            "_id":"User001",
            "Name":"UserName001",
            "email":"user001@eg.com"
            }
         },
         {"_id": "002",
           "CommentedBy":{
            "_id":"User002",
            "Name":"UserName002",
            "email":"user001@eg.com"
            }
         },
         {"_id": "003",
          "CommentedBy":{
            "_id":"User003",
            "Name":"UserName003",
            "email":"user001@eg.com"
            }
         }
    ]
}
```

The user document consist of more than just username and id. Using multiple lookups may end up referring `User001` Multiple times.

**Expected Result**

```
{
        "PostId":"Post001",
        "Comments":[
             {"_id": "001",
              "CommentedBy":{
                "_id":"User001",
                "Name":"UserName001",
                "email":"user001@eg.com",
                "Group":"Marketing",
                "Location":"India"                }
             },
             {"_id": "002",
               "CommentedBy":{
                "_id":"User002",
                "Name":"UserName002",
                "email":"user002@eg.com",
                "Group":"Engineering",
                "Location":"USA"         
                }
             },
             {"_id": "003",
              "CommentedBy":{
               "_id":"User002",
                "Name":"UserName002",
                "email":"user002@eg.com",
                "Group":"Engineering",
                "Location":"USA"      
                }
             }
        ]
    }
```

The UserDocument would look something like this

```
User = [
  {
  "_id":"User001",
  "Name":"UserName001",
  "email":"user001@eg.com",
  "Group":"Marketing",
  "Location":"USA"      
  },
  {
  "_id":"User002",
  "Name":"UserName002",
  "email":"user002@eg.com",
  "Group":"Engineering",
  "Location":"USA"      
  }
  ...
  ...
]
```

The query I tried

```
db.getCollection('Posts').aggregate([
    {$lookup:{
           from: "User",
           localField: "Comments.CommentedBy._id",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "Comments.CommentedBy"
   }},
])
```

1. Will this be efficient for n-posts with n-comments
2. Will mongo do some kind of optimization when looking up `User002` since it needs to be looked up twice.
3. If CommentedBy is a list of user how to do $lookup in that case

Comment: could you show your query? and the expected result you want?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Updated with query and more details

Comment: From where Group and Location comes? Inside commentedBy

Comment: From the UserDocument

Comment: You have to use `$unwind` if your `user_id` is embedded inside the `Comments` array. Or you have to change your document structure to do this more efficiently.

Comment: What change to the document structure do you suggest?

Comment: Use another collection for comments and save  userid with each comment in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180050/discussion-between-bhavani-ravi-and-anthony-winzlet).